# Get Non Pre-Windows 2000 Group Name from SID

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a SID which represents a group on a different domain.

I am trying to get the group name using:

```
$objSid = New-Object 'System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier'($Sid)
$objUser = $objSid.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
$groupName = $objUser.Value
```

However this returns the pre-Windows 2000 name which is different to the actual group name (it has `A_` at the front).

How can I get the real group name instead of the pre-Windows 2000 group name?

EDIT:
iRon mentioned I can use `(Get-ADGroup $GroupName).Name`, however I now need to write this in C#. The first part is easy to translate, however how can I get the C# code for the `Get-ADGroup` commandlet?

Comment: `(Get-ADGroup $GroupName).Name`

Comment: Thanks iRon. Do you know how to do that in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the pre-Windows 2000 name is just the samAccountName.
So to get the group name, you just need to search for the group with samAccountName = pre-Windows 2000 name.
This can easily be done in C# using DirectorySearcher.